# Execute all tasks even if one throws an exception

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I got the following method:

```
public async Task PublishAsync<TApplicationEvent>(TApplicationEvent e)
    where TApplicationEvent : ApplicationEvent
{
    using (var scope = _container.CreateScope())
    {
        var implementations = scope.ResolveAll<IApplicationEventSubscriber<TApplicationEvent>>();
        var tasks = implementations.Select(x => x.HandleAsync(e));
        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            EventPublished(this, new EventPublishedEventArgs(scope, e, true));
        }
        catch
        {
            EventPublished(this, new EventPublishedEventArgs(scope, e, false));
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that all tasks would be executed before an exception being thrown, but it seems like the method aborts when the first task thrown an exception.

Can I configure `WhenAll` to execute all tasks and generate an AggregateException with all failures before returning?

Comment: That's what `WhenAll` does: ["If any of the supplied tasks completes in a faulted state, the returned task will also complete in a Faulted state, where its exceptions will contain the aggregation of the set of unwrapped exceptions from each of the supplied tasks."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's exactly what `WhenAll` *does* do.  However, when you `await` a task that throws an aggregate exception that has multiple exceptions within it, it will rethrow just the first exception within the aggregate exception, rather than rethrowing the aggregate exception itself.  (This is because the vast majority of tasks that throw exceptions will never have multiple expressions within the aggregate, so having the exception unwrapped is almost always the desired behavior.)

Simply hold onto a reference to the `Task` before you `await` it so that you can access the aggregate exception later on, or simply don't `await` the result of `WhenAll` and instead use manual continuations.

Comment: @jgauffin I suggest you inspect the state of all of the tasks in `tasks` when `WhenAll` completes.  My guess is you aren't configuring your method as you expect, if that is the problem you're having.

Comment: read my second update. What do you mean with `you aren't configuring your method as you expect`

Comment: @jgauffin Either your `tasks` sequence doesn't contain all of the operations you expect it to, or they aren't completing when you think they are.

Comment: @jgauffin No, an aggregate exception is returned by `WhenAll` in either case.  `Wait` rethrows it directly, `await` unwraps the first exception from it and rethrows *that*.  In either case, the `Task` itself isn't completed until all tasks it was given have completed, which is what you're asking for.  If something isn't done yet when that task is completed then you didn't pass that `Task` to `WhenAll`.

Comment: @jgauffin The probability that you've found a bug in `WhenAll` that results in it completing before all of the given tasks complete is vanishingly small.  It's far, far more likely that you're not testing what you think you're testing, and either not passing what you think you're passing to `WhenAll` or not properly observing the effects.  It sounds like your testing framework is simply getting in your way here.  Just create two tasks explicitly that do anything you want, with at least one faulting, pass them both to `WhenAll`, and see that they are all completed after the task completes.

Comment: And I explained to you exactly why in my answer, along with several possible resolutions to your problem.  It sounds like you haven't tried *any* of them, nor even acknowledged the very simple and straightforward explanation.  That you seem convinced that you should be using `Wait` (when you absolutely should not be) is rather concerning.

Comment: I misread `Simply hold onto a reference to the Task before you await it so that you can access the aggregate exception later on`. That works :) Thank you for being patient. Is it OK if I modify the answer with the working solution?

Comment: @jgauffin No, I very intentionally did not include the code in the answer as I felt it would inhibit readers taking the time to actually understand the problem, instead only copying some code without realizing why the change is important.

Answer (score 5):

Task.WhenAll() -> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have completed.

It will complete the execution of all the tasks irrespective of what happens in the individual task.

Exception in one of the Tasks in given collection of task will not stop the execution of others.

```
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception("test1");
        });
        tasks.Add(t1);

        Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception("test2");
        });
        tasks.Add(t2);

        Task t3 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pseudo Work");
        });
        tasks.Add(t3);

        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Only t1 & t2 will qualify and t3 will be successful (Pseudo Work will be printed on console) 
            var exceptions = tasks.Where(t => t.Exception != null).Select(t => t.Exception);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I run the following sample, all tasks complete but it still throws, which I believe is expected:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskWhenAllTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Task task = Test();

                Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { task });

                Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Task errored.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static async Task Test()
        {
            var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); throw new Exception("Test1 exception"); });
            var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); Console.WriteLine("Task 2 complete."); });
            var task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250); Console.WriteLine("Task 3 complete."); });

            await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] {task1, task2, task3 });
        }
    }
}
```